# Allow login using username or email in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Now I've followed the Laravel documentation on how to allow usernames during authentication, but it takes away the ability to use the email. I want to allow users to use their username or email to login. How do I go about this?

I've added this code to the LoginController as per Laravel's Documentation and it only allows username for login. I want it to accept username or email for login.

```
public function username () {
    return 'username';
}
```

Comment: Are you using the default auth by laravel? if yes, you have to choose either username or email. not both. usrname returns a string, not an array. If you want custom login, you have to write the logic yourself.

Comment: how do i do that? I'm not sure which files to edit if i want to write my own logic.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Follow instructions from this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users

Then you can check for the user input like this

```
$username = $request->username; //the input field has name='username' in form

if(filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //user sent their email 
    Auth::attempt(['email' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
} else {
    //they sent their username instead 
    Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
}

//was any of those correct ?
if ( Auth::check() ) {
    //send them where they are going 
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}

//Nope, something wrong during authentication 
return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
    'credentials' => 'Please, check your credentials'
]);
```

This is just a sample. THere are countless various approaches you can take to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 63):

I think a simpler way is to just override the username method in LoginController:

```
public function username()
{
   $login = request()->input('login');
   $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
   request()->merge([$field => $login]);
   return $field;
}
```

Comment: The best thing about code (and also the worst, because it is the culprit of imposter syndrome) is that there's always a simpler way. Nice solution :)

Answer (score 15):

Open your `LoginController.php` file.

1. Add this reference

   ```
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   ```
2. And override the **credentials method**

   ```
   protected function credentials(Request $request)
   {
       $field = filter_var($request->get($this->username()), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
       ? 'email'
       : 'username';

       return [
           $field => $request->get($this->username()),
           'password' => $request->password,
       ];
   }
   ```

Successfully tested in **Laravel 5.7.11**

Comment: Interestingly, the laravel 5.8 documentation recommends the username() function, but that didn't work for me.  But this crententials() approach does.

Comment: Wow! This works like a charm in 2023 too. Does it have any security threat?

Answer (score 4):

You need to override `protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)` method from `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` Trait in your LoginController
i.e. in my LoginController class

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request) {

    $identity = $request->get("usernameOrEmail");
    $password = $request->get("password");

    return \Auth::attempt([
        filter_var($identity, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username' => $identity,
        'password' => $password
    ]);
}
```

Your LoginController class should use Trait `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` in order to override `attemptLogin` method i.e.

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

     use \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
     .......
     .......
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think its even more simple, just override the method from **AuthenticatesUsers** traits, credentials method in your LoginController. Here I have implemented to login with either email or phone. You can change it to fit your needs.

**LoginController.php**

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    if(is_numeric($request->get('email'))){
        return ['phone'=>$request->get('email'),'password'=>$request->get('password')];
    }
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}
```

Comment: This works fine even if you implement it in LoginController which is a more subtle and safe way.

Comment: Nicely done, upon Laravel upgrade, this is a safer way for implementation

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it:

```
// get value of input from form (email or username in the same input)
 $email_or_username = $request->input('email_or_username');

 // check if $email_or_username is an email
 if(filter_var($email_or_username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // user sent his email 

    // check if user email exists in database
    $user_email = User::where('email', '=', $request->input('email_or_username'))->first();

    if ($user_email) { // email exists in database
       if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email_or_username, 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
          // success
       } else {
          // error password
       }
    } else {
       // error: user not found
    }

 } else { // user sent his username 

    // check if username exists in database
    $username = User::where('name', '=', $request->input('email_or_username'))->first();

    if ($username) { // username exists in database
       if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $email_or_username, 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
          // success
       } else {
          // error password
       }
    } else {
       // error: user not found
    }
 }
```

I believe there is a shorter way to do that, but for me this works and is easy to understand.

Comment: Check for user exists in the database if Auth::attempt is already doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function username()
{
    //return ‘identity’;
    $login = request()->input('identity');
    $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'phone';
    request()->merge([$field => $login]);

    return $field;
}


protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $messages = [
        'identity.required' => 'Email or username cannot be empty',
        'email.exists' => 'Email or username already registered',
        'phone.exists' => 'Phone No is already registered',
        'password.required' => 'Password cannot be empty',
    ];

    $request->validate([
        'identity' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'string|exists:users',
        'phone' => 'numeric|exists:users',
    ], $messages);
}
```

https://dev.to/pramanadiputra/laravel-how-to-let-user-login-with-email-or-username-j2h

Answer (score -1):

```
This solution of "Rabah G" works for me in Laravel 5.2. I modified a litle but is the same

$loginType = request()->input('useroremail');
$this->username = filter_var($loginType, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
request()->merge([$this->username => $loginType]);
return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, this is the solution I got thanks to yours.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request) { 

$login = request()->input('email'); 

// Check whether username or email is being used
$field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'user_name'; 
return [ 
   $field    => $request->get('email'), 
  'password' => $request->password, 
  'verified' => 1 
]; 
}
```

Comment: You should NOT edit Laravel source... it will be wiped out on upgrade